# Androidアプリ開発～既存のＤＢの読み込み～

Tags: android, android-studio, database

Androidアプリ開発でのDBの利用方法についての質問です。

〇実現したいこと
アプリ内でDBをCREATEするのではなく、既存のDBをアプリ内に取り込んで利用する。

〇疑問
1、以下のサイト（http://y-anz-m.blogspot.jp/2011/01/android-sqline-database.html）を参考にassetsフォルダ内にDBファイルをおいたところ次のようなエラーが出た。
[image: Projectのassetsフォルダ内に既存のＤＢを保存したときのエラー]

SQLiteで確認したところ文字コードはUTF-8になっているので何が間違っているのかわからない。

2、そもそも既存のDBを使用する方法はほかにはないのか（探したところウェブサイトに有益な情報はなかった）。

〇発生したエラー
「File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'」

Androidアプリ開発に詳しい方、回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーの内容が書かれていると思われる部分が字化けしていて理解できません。どんなエラーなのか把握できているのなら、それを質問に追加してください。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。エラー内容は上記の画像に載っている通り「File was loaded in wrong encoding:'UTF-8'」です。

Comment: 画像ではなくテキストを張り付けてください。

Comment: テキストは「File was loaded in wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'」です。アプリ開発自体初心者でここの掲示板も初めてなので的外れなことをしていたら申し訳ありません。これで大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！ただいま外出先なので確認できる状態になったらまた更新しなおしてみます。

Answer (score 1):

sqliteのデータベースファイルはテキストではないので、ソースコードのように中身を直接エディタで見たり編集したりすることはできません。

Comment: そうなんですね！一回このデータベースを使って最後までコードを完成させてみます。

Comment: suzukisさんのおっしゃる通りでした！AndroidStudio内でDBの内容を見ることはできませんが、そのままコードを完成させてみたら無事に既存のDBを利用することが出来ました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score -1):

エラーメッセージ：「File was loaded in wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'」(直訳：ファイルはエンコードするのは不適切なUTF-8として収納されました)と
質問中の「SQLiteで確認したところ文字コードはUTF-8になっている」のふたつから推測されるのは、
『assetsフォルダ内に置いたDBファイルで使われている文字コードがUTF-8ではない』という事です。

既存のDBに由来するファイルかと思われますが、そのファイルがSQLiteでは読み込めていないので、ファイルの生成方法の見直し（文字コードをUTF-8に指定してexportする等）や文字コードの変換などを検討してください。